# Return a string from function to main

Tags: c, string, function, program-entry-point

I want to return a string from a function (in the example *funzione*) to main. How to do this? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE (10)

/* TODO*/ funzione (void)
{
    char stringFUNC[SIZE];

    strcpy (stringFUNC, "Example");

    return /* TODO*/;
}

int main()
{
    char stringMAIN[SIZE];

    /* TODO*/

    return 0;
}
```

**[EDITED]** For those who need it, the complete version of the previous code (but without *stringMAIN*) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE (10)

char *funzione (void)
{
    char *stringa = malloc(SIZE);
    strcpy (stringa, "Example");

    return stringa;
} 

int main()
{
    char *ptr = funzione();

    printf ("%s\n", ptr);

    free (ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you even try to search this?

Comment: If you don't understand it, you should continue searching each piece that you don't understand and learn to apply it to your problem. Stackoverflow isn't meant to do your work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A string is a block of memory of variable length, and C cannot returns such objects (at least not without breaking compatibility with code that assumes strings cannot be returned)

You can return a pointer to a string, and in this case you have two options:

Option 1. Create the string dynamically within the function:

```
char *funzione (void)
{
    char *res = malloc (strlen("Example")+1);  /* or enough room to 
                                                  keep your string */
    strcpy (res, "Example");    
    return res;
}
```

In this case, the function that receives the resulting string is responsible for deallocate the memory used to build it. Failure to do so will lead to memory leaks in your program.

```
int main()
{
  char *str;

  str = funzione();
  /* do stuff with str */
  free (str);
  return 0;
}
```

Option 2. Create a static string inside your function and returns it.

```
char *funzione (void)
{
  static char str[MAXLENGTHNEEDED];

  strcpy (str, "Example");
  return str;
}
```

In this case you don't need to deallocate the string, but be aware that you won't be able to call this function from different threads in your program. This function is not thread-safe.

```
int main()
{
  char *str;

  str = funzione();
  /* do stuff with str */
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the object returned is a pointer to the string, so on both methods, the variable that receives the result from `funzione()` is not a char array, but a pointer to a char array.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10

const char *funzione (void){
    const char *string = "Example";

    if(strlen(string) >= SIZE)
        return "";

    return string;
}

int main(void){
    char stringMAIN[SIZE];

    strcpy(stringMAIN, funzione());

    printf("%s", stringMAIN);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not bad :) I thought about it. +1

Comment: Why `if(strlen(string)>=10) return "";` ?

Comment: @use Because the expected character of SIZE that no more can hold. By concept whether truncate the contents.

Comment: Ok thank you! But you have not allocate memory because it's a _const char_, right?

Comment: @user yes, It may be a return const char * simply if it returns preset character string as a meaning when it returns a string from the function (such as a string literal (as `const char *`)).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as

```
char *funzione (void)
{
    char *stringFUNC = malloc(SIZE);
    strcpy (stringFUNC, "Example");

    return stringFUNC;
}
```

In `main`, call it as

```
int main()
{
    char stringMAIN[SIZE];
    char *ptr = funzione ()
    ...

    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `free`.

Comment: @user; What? Be more specific.

Comment: Ok thank you, and excuse me for the trivial question.

Comment: @Nabla; You are right. But I left `char stringMAIN[SIZE];` as it is because I am not sure why it is there :)

Comment: `strcpy(stringMAIN, ptr);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY; I can understand. But no need of this.